# Increase Knowledge Article Like Count via API

Tags: knowledge, articles, salesforce-cms

Currently Salesforce is used as CMS(Content Management System) on a different platform. This platform displays Knowledge Articles to guest users on a public website.

When a guest clicks on 'like/dislike' on the Article, the count of likes/dislikes in Salesforce should also increase.

Is there an API available to do that? or any APEX code?

Comment: You can see the following [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/290624/where-does-like-dislikes-stores-when-we-give-knowledge-article-feedback/290632#290632) for information. I think the issue will be specific to your need to do this for guest users as I believe a vote can only be inserted (once) for actual users.

Comment: thank you Kris, tried this and it works for internal Users...need something similar for guest Users...since website(external) Users are different from internal Users